# How to add a network printer on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp

I need to setup a HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125nw on my Ubuntu 15.10.

As you can see from the screenshot, I can see the printer from my network and add it.

After this dialog it install the drivers and tell me to print a TEST PAGE, I click PRINT.

At this point, I can see the test page in the queue list, but the job is always STOPPED, this happen with any documents I want to print.

Using cups it tells me `stopped "Filter failed"` Printer is on `Idle - "Rendering completed"`

What could be the problem? How to print? Thanks.

Other details from cups logs

```
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] Processing page 1...
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] Set job-printer-state-message to "Processing page 1...", current level=INFO
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] prnt/hpcups/Hbpl1.cpp 52: Hbpl1 constructor : m_szLanguage = HBPL1STATE: +hplip.plugin-error
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 486: m_Job initialization failed with error = 48
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] prnt/backend/hp.c 919: ERROR: null print job total=0
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] PID 5476 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/hp) exited with no errors.
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] PID 5475 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups) stopped with status 1.
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] Processing page 2...
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] Rendering completed
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] PID 5474 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) exited with no errors.
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] End of messages
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] printer-state=3(idle)
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [05/Dec/2015:16:20:54 +0100] [Job 13] printer-state-reasons=none
```

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem recently.  It was a Canon so may not apply, hence posting as comment, but I fixed it like this:

I went into Printer Properties for the printer. The Device URI looked like this:
    cnijbe2://Canon/?port=net&serial=F4-91-39-42-53-Z1 (Not my printer's real MAC address but you get the idea)
I changed it to
   ipp://192.168.1.6 (where that is the LAN IP of the printer, permanently assigned in my router)  and then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same problem by installing `hplip` manually. Run:

```
 sudo apt-get install hplip
```

and then run:

```
hp-setup
```

which will open a GUI where you can search/add your printer.

[image]

You could also directly install the GUI by:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Run it from dash and follow the directions.

[image]

Comment: Sir @Ron, does it work for non-HP printers?

Comment: May not. But there's no harm in trying!

Comment: It works Sir! :D But it cannot help to connect to a network printer under Windows 7 machine.